# Random deadlocks SQL Server 2012 using ODBC Driver 17 and simple "Select * FROM" Stored Procedures

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, deadlock

I'm getting random deadlock errors in my application on sometimes the simplest of stored procedures.

The application environment where I'm experiencing the error uses the GUNICORN server in production connecting to SQL Server 2012 via pyodbc and ODBCDriver 17.

The application environment does utilize [HashiCrop Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/databases/mssql.html), this plugin generates database credentials dynamically based on configured roles for the MSSQL database, the logins expire around 10 mins.

An example of an error is below

> pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'EXEC CHAMP.[dbo].[SP_dashboard_load_beta_list]': ('40001', '[40001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Transaction (Process ID 74) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction. (1205) (SQLExecDirectW)')

This is the stored procedure

**CHAMP.[dbo].[SP_dashboard_load_beta_list]**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_dashboard_load_beta_list]

    AS

    BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

        SELECT id, short_name, long_name 
        FROM CHAMP.dbo.champ_dw_index_master 
        WHERE is_market_beta='Y' 
        ORDER BY short_name

    END
```

Is there any thing obvious as to how such a simple stored procedure could throw an error?

**XML Report**

```
<deadlock>
 <victim-list>
  <victimProcess id="process8741e1c38" />
 </victim-list>
 <process-list>
  <process id="process8741e1c38" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="METADATA: database_id = 1 PERMISSIONS(class = 100, major_id = 0)" waittime="4651" ownerId="1576984016" transactionname="Load Permission Object Cache" lasttranstarted="2019-10-14T16:41:33.470" XDES="0x61bea9810" lockMode="Sch-S" schedulerid="2" kpid="33684" status="suspended" spid="74" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2019-10-14T16:41:33.473" lastbatchcompleted="2019-10-14T16:41:33.460" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.460" clientapp="python3.7" hostname="3702124fa30a" hostpid="245" loginname="v-approle-champ_readaccess_PRO-giVLBtHPPhdM4u8GHJDw-1571031688" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="0" currentdb="19" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
   <executionStack>
    <frame procname="CHAMP.dbo.SP_dashboard_load_beta_list" line="1" stmtstart="-1" sqlhandle="0x030013004fa3d411b251170178aa000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_dashboard_load_beta_list]

AS

BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT id, short_name, long_name 
    FROM CHAMP.dbo.champ_dw_index_master 
    WHERE is_market_beta='Y' 
    ORDER BY short_name

END    </frame>
    <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" sqlhandle="0x01001300ced65b00f0d9ce750200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
EXEC CHAMP.[dbo].[SP_dashboard_load_beta_list]    </frame>
   </executionStack>
   <inputbuf>
EXEC CHAMP.[dbo].[SP_dashboard_load_beta_list]   </inputbuf>
  </process>
  <process id="process87f025c38" taskpriority="0" logused="1260" waitresource="METADATA: database_id = 19 DATABASE_PRINCIPAL(principal_id = 6)" waittime="4625" ownerId="1576983991" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2019-10-14T16:41:33.437" XDES="0x39e1cf818" lockMode="Sch-M" schedulerid="3" kpid="37524" status="suspended" spid="62" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2019-10-14T16:41:33.500" lastbatchcompleted="2019-10-14T16:41:33.487" lastattention="2019-10-07T15:25:11.327" clientapp="go-mssqldb" hostname="647f96b1d42e" hostpid="0" loginname="gwsampso" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="1576983991" currentdb="19" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
   <executionStack>
    <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" sqlhandle="0x01001300eb293f1990ff88480500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
ALTER ROLE [TableSelector] ADD MEMBER [v-approle-champ_readaccess_PRO-1RrrKqWYm9STdbN95l36-1571031692]    </frame>
   </executionStack>
   <inputbuf>
ALTER ROLE [TableSelector] ADD MEMBER [v-approle-champ_readaccess_PRO-1RrrKqWYm9STdbN95l36-1571031692]   </inputbuf>
  </process>
 </process-list>
 <resource-list>
  <metadatalock subresource="PERMISSIONS" classid="class = 100, major_id = 0" dbid="1" id="lock4a21b4e00" mode="Sch-M">
   <owner-list>
    <owner id="process87f025c38" mode="Sch-M" />
   </owner-list>
   <waiter-list>
    <waiter id="process8741e1c38" mode="Sch-S" requestType="wait" />
   </waiter-list>
  </metadatalock>
  <metadatalock subresource="DATABASE_PRINCIPAL" classid="principal_id = 6" dbid="19" id="lock4a7c17f00" mode="Sch-S">
   <owner-list>
    <owner id="process8741e1c38" mode="Sch-S" />
   </owner-list>
   <waiter-list>
    <waiter id="process87f025c38" mode="Sch-M" requestType="wait" />
   </waiter-list>
  </metadatalock>
 </resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

**GRAPH**

[image]

Comment: I believe the running command ALTER ROLE [TableSelector] ADD MEMBER ... is the root cause. Sch-M is a lock mode of Schema Modification.

Comment: Great thanks for your comment @DatNguyen. So the dynamic creation of user credentials is potentially locking my schema?